# What are the requirements for non-interference and does it hold for my code snippets

Tags: security

I having trouble understanding weather or not non-interferance holds for hte following code snippets:
1.

```
pr_x = pr_x + ((pr_x + 1) % 3);
pb_y = ((pr_x % 3) == 0);
```

2. 

```
if (pb_x == pr_y * 3)
    pb_x = 15;
else if (pb_x == pr_y * 2)
    pb_x = 42;
else
    skip;
```

3. 

```
pb_x = pr_y;
if (pr_y % 2 == 0)
    pb_x = pb_x + 1;
else
    pb_x = pb_x + 2;
pb_z = pb_x % 2;
pb_x = 0;
```

My current thinking is that non-interference holds for non of the code snippets.